# Checking proxies with python

Tags: python, python-requests, proxy, pycurl

I want to check if a proxy is alived or not using python. To do that, my approach was to use request like:

```
import requests

proxies = []

for i in proxies:
    prox = {"prox": f"http://{i}"}
    r = requests.get("http://google.es", proxies=prox, timeout=5)

    latency = r.elapsed 
    latency = int(latency.total_seconds() * 1000)
    print(r.status_code)
```

So I was happy with this solution, but then I found out that using a different approach the result was different. With this request code I obtain status_code = 200 and latencies < 100 for a list of 10 proxies. However, if I use ProxyChecker which is based on pycurl:

```
from proxy_checker import ProxyChecker

for i in proxies:
    print(i)
    a = checker.check_proxy(i)
    print(a)
```

for the same list only 3 out of 10 are working. My question is: Why is there this difference? What's wrong with my request approach? or why requests says it found google using these proxies?

**EDIT**
Do not use ProxyChecker version 0.6. It's outdated and 50% of the time does not work. Check this version https://github.com/Scolymus/proxy-checker-python

Answer (score 0):

As I was told, the reason is the following:

The proxy-checker is using a custom header, which has a specific value (lel). Requests is not using this header by default.
Here is the proxy-checker code:

```
def check_proxy(self, proxy):
    if not proxy:
        return None
    try:
        #if self.headers:
        #    curl.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, self.headers.items())
        curl.setopt(pycurl.PROXY, proxy)
        curl.setopt(pycurl.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13')
        curl.setopt(pycurl.URL, self.check_url)
        curl.perform()

        if curl.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE) == 200:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    except pycurl.error as e:
        return False
```

You can test the same proxies with the same custom header by adding it to your headers dictionary:

```
    ...
    headers = {'lel': 'lel'}
    r = requests.get("http://google.es", headers=headers, proxies=prox, timeout=5)
    ...
```

Comment: I don't understand your answer. Why inserting a user-agent should change it? I tried putting the same user agent, and the answer is ok with request too, while it's not with pycurl